# Magento: Cannot find named PHP session module (file)

Tags: php, magento

I am debugging an issue with an extension and turned on MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE.  Now I'm getting this error:

```
    Warning: session_module_name(): Cannot find named PHP session module (file)  in
/Users/spdaly/Projects/td-site/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 67
```

I chmod'd 777 and cleared my cache.  I haven't seen this error before.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So...I should RTM. Public humiliation accepted...

app/etc/local.xml had

```
<session_save><![CDATA[file]]></session_save>
```

needs to be plural

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

I hope this keeps someone else from having this issue...

Comment: I too feel like a noob ;)