# Cannot find named PHP session module magento 1.7 version

Tags: magento

I found below error in system.log

Warning: session_module_name(): Cannot find named PHP session module (file)  in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 67

Can anyone know solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento: Cannot find named PHP session module (file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246133/magento-cannot-find-named-php-session-module-file)

Comment: Does your issue solve or still looking for answer?

Comment: Yes Its resolve.
Used <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save> in local.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve such type of warning error one should have to use below code in 
layout file.
Its worked for me.
![CDATA[files]] in session_save node